# How to create an app to copy a file from one folder to another using Java in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I want create an app which can copy a file from a folder let's say download folder of my Android device and paste it into an another folder ( any folder of my choice ). How can I make it.

Answer (score 1):

Copying files from one folder to another is pretty easy. You can just use `Files.copy`

```
Path sourceDirectory = Paths.get("/Users/personal/tutorials/source");
    Path targetDirectory = Paths.get("/Users/personal/tutorials/target");

    //copy source to target using Files Class
    Files.copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);
```

You now have to build something where you can select a source and a target folder.